# Is it possible to block requests from outside places?

Tags: php, server, request

I have my php program running on server A and server A sends requests to server B to get data. This server B is owned by client and hosted in his company. The client wants this online system to work only in their company. Is it possible for server A to understand the request is comming from same place that hosts server B and show data, else if request is comming from another network like a home etc the data should be hidden.

Comment: you can put in place an IP based restriction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly this would be better done from a network/firewall standpoint. You can do it in PHP, but it is way easier to fake.

To do it in PHP, simply look up the IP address in the request on server B. Something like this:

```
$access_allowed = FALSE;
   $allowed_ip = Server_A_ip;
   //check ip address
   if ($allowed_ip == $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']){
     $access_allowed = TRUE;
   }
   //exit if not allowed
   if ($access_allowed == FALSE){
     exit;
   }
```

Comment: much better to do it via apache

Comment: @Dagon For sure.  This was just a way to do it in PHP.  It really should be done in apache or a firewall.

Comment: @Dagon Guys thank you for the answers. I don't know much about apache and server stuff can you give me some links to search about it? Or how should I google it?